# When I saved the file (Ctrl + S) the texture disappeared

Tags: texturing

I was painting the textures onto the model when I decided to do an incremental save as to not lose all my work, so I pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>S</kbd> and saved the blend file.

When I looked at Blender again (I did not close Blender at all) the object was black and I can't find the texture image I saved? Sorry, I'm really new to Blender. Here's a screen:

[image]

Comment: It's gone for good, you have no option but to redo the texture. One you have a new texture **you need to save the texture as an image first** on your hard drive.

Answer (score 0):

I advise is that you go on UV / Image Editor and choose the Image menu and click save the image, choose the output file format the image and click save the image, so you do not lose your work.